# JAXB how to force a certain order in unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, hashcode, unmarshalling

I have the following XML:

```
<rootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <collection>
        <link referenceId="id1" foo="foo"/>
    </collection>
    <referencable id="id1" name="bar"/>
</rootElement>
```

I have written some classes that this XML should be unmarshalled to via JAXB (code below). Note the following points:

1. `Link` has overridden `equals` and `getHashCode` methods. The referenced object (given by `referenceId`) influences the hash code. That means: **A `Link` with no `referenceId` set has a different hash code than when its `referenceId` is set.**
2. `Collection` contains a `HashSet<Link>` which is filled with `Link`s during unmarshalling. That means: **A `Link` that has been put into the `Set` must not change its hash code afterwards; else it will not be findable by the `contains` method any more!**

When unmarshalling with the following code

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\rootElement.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootElement.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
RootElement rootElement = (RootElement)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
```

the `Link` ends up unfindable, which can easily seen by calling

```
Set<Link> links = rootElement.getCollection().getLink();
boolean contains = links.contains(links.iterator().next()); // returns false
```

So my question is: **How can I make sure that the `Link` is only added to the `HashSet<Link>` AFTER its `referenceId` has been set?**

- Changing the XML is no option; I get it from a third party and am not allowed to modify it*. (Switching the `collection` and the `referencable` elements would resolve the issue because then, `Link` gets its `referenceId` set before it is added to the `Set<Link>`.)
- Changing the `HashSet` to some collection that does not make use of `getHashCode` is no option; I need a `contains` method with `O(1)` performance*.
- Changing the `getHashCode` method of `Link` is no option; I need it that way. Else it becomes useless.

*The real-life scenario is about huge XMLs where the collection contains thousands of links.

---

**RootElement:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "collection",
    "referencable"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "rootElement")
public class RootElement {

    protected Collection collection;
    protected Referencable referencable;
    public Referencable getReferencable() { return referencable; }
    public void setReferencable(Referencable referencable) { this.referencable = referencable; }
    public Collection getCollection() { return collection; }
    public void setCollection(Collection collection) { this.collection = collection; }
}
```

**Collection:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Collection", propOrder = {"link"})
public class Collection {

    protected Set<Link> link;
    public Set<Link> getLink() {
        if (link == null) { link = new HashSet<Link>(); }
        return this.link;
    }
}
```

**Link:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Link")
public class Link
{
    @XmlAttribute(name = "referenceId", required = true)
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
    protected Object referenceId;
    public Object getReferenceId() { return referenceId; }
    public void setReferenceId(Object value) { this.referenceId = value; }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "foo", required = true)
    protected String foo;
    public String getFoo() { return foo; }
    public void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((foo == null) ? 0 : foo.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((referenceId == null) ? 0 : referenceId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) { return true; }
        if (obj == null) { return false; }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) { return false; }
        Link other = (Link) obj;
        if (foo == null) { if (other.foo != null) { return false; } }
        else if (!foo.equals(other.foo)) { return false; }
        if (referenceId == null) { if (other.referenceId != null) { return false; } }
        else if (!referenceId.equals(other.referenceId)) { return false; }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Referencable:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Referencable")
public class Referencable
{
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected String id;
    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String value) { this.id = value; }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String value) { this.name = value; }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) { return true; }
        if (!super.equals(obj)) { return false; }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) { return false; }
        Referencable other = (Referencable) obj;
        if (name == null) { if (other.name != null) { return false; } }
        else if (!name.equals(other.name)) { return false; }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't control when idrefs are resolved.

Workarounds:

- You can remove the hashcode of the referenced object from the hashcode of `Link`. It will still be a consistent hashcode (but with worse performance)
- Make the collection a list, unless you have hundreds of entries you should barely see a performance impact.
- Make the `getLink()` something like this

  ```
  protected List<Link> link;
  @XmlTransient
  private boolean reinit = false;
  public Set<Link> getLink() {
     if (!reinit) { 
        if(link != null) {
           link= new HashSet<Link>(link); 
        } else {
           link= new HashSet<Link>(); 
        }
        reinit = true
     } 
     return this.link;
  }
  ```